# drop down menu using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to populate a drop down menu using php

Here is my code

```
          <? 
        $dbstate = new DB();
        if (!$dbstate->open()) {
          die ($dbstate->error());
        }
        if (!$dbstate->query("SELECT ename FROM external_detail order by eid")) {
          die ($dbstate->error());
        }
          ?>
                <select name="selstate" >
                <option value="0">Select state</option>
            <?
                while ($row = $dbstate->fetchAssoc()) {
            ?>          
                <option value="<?=$row['eid']?>">
                <?=$row['ename'] ?>
                </option>
        <?
                         }
                    $dbstate->freeResult();
                    $dbstate->close();
        ?>
              </select>
```

my drop down menu is not being populated 
can you please tell me where am i going wrong...thnx for the help

Comment: What is the actual problem with your code?

Comment: @juergend the formatting is.

Comment: my drop down menu is not being populated

Comment: where is the worng, database or dropdownlist, check it

Comment: where do you select `eid` to use `$row['eid']` ?

Answer (score 3):

You're not echoing anything:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row['eid']?>"><?php echo $row['ename'] ?></option>
```

Maybe you meant to use the short tag for echo (`<?=`), but you didn't

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting data to HTML pages, otherwise you're prone to SQL injection (and things will go wrong when characters like `<` are in `$row['eid']`).

Comment: Agree on escaping before output (to avoid breaking the html, too), but what SQL injection have to do with escaping html? Maybe you mean XSS attacks?

Comment: Aargh, I just saw too much code that's prone to SQL injection, that I accidentally wrote "SQL injection" where I actually meant to write "XSS attacks".

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the '=' from your echo shorthand...

```
<option value="<?= $row['eid']?>">
    <?= $row['ename'] ?>
</option>
```